# Configuring jenkins with bitbucket private repository

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to integrate my private repository in BitBucket with Jenkins, I am following the same exact steps as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTlAssPBKBs), but my error is not resolving.

The following image shows the error I am getting. How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: click the "enter image description ".it will give the image of my error.Thanks

Comment: And you've confirmed that nothing is blocking SSH traffic, and that you've added the key Jenkins is using to either the repo (as an access key) or to a user account?

Comment: nothing is blocking the ssh traffic and I generated the ssh keys on my Jenkins server and used the public key in access keys of bitbucket and private key in Jenkins credentials

Comment: Thanks for your time Jim, I resolved it by installing git in my Jenkins server.it was not installed before.